# Press Q to quit in c# without a Console.Read method?

Tags: c#

This is my first time on here and I'm also new to C# so bear with me.
I was given a task to code a program that will print out the times tables up to 20 for a user input number, and keep asking for numbers and printing out the times tables until the user presses q to quit.

I'm having trouble with breaking the loop and I'm not quite sure why. Here is the program so far:

```
        //variable declarations
        int number;


        //output title
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the 20 Times Tables Calculator");

        //output prompt for number
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 20 (inclusive).");

        //infinite loop
        for (; ; )
        {


            //input number
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //validate number
            while (number > 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number smaller than 20.");
                number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            //calculate multiple x number
            //increment i
            //repeat until i = 20
            for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + i + " x " + number + " = " + i * number);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter another number or press q to quit.");

            //break loop
            //press q to quit
            while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q') ;

        }

         //retain console screen
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want continue program if user enter a number?

Comment: Is it acceptable if the user has to press q and then press Enter?

Answer (score 4):

1) Instead of the following line at the beginning:

```
number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Read a string from the console and check if it is "q", if not continue:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
if(line == "q")
    break;
number = int.Parse(line);
```

2) Delete the following line, you don't need it any more:

```
while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q') ;
```

Please note that this will allow the user to quit even in the first loop.